# ImportError: No module named itertools

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I am trying to run this script:

```
    python schema2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "schema2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import itertools
ImportError: No module named itertools
```

and I am continuosly getting this error. my python version is 2.7.12...any idea why?

Comment: Your Python installation seems broken. What OS are you using? How did you install Python? What does your Python path look like (`python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`)?

Comment: Have you done something weird with your `sys.path` inside the script (or something it imports before this), or `PYTHONPATH` in your shell?

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to uninstall Python and re-install it. itertools is a standard library and should be included.

Comment: I ask because I once stupidly typo'd `sys.path[:] = …` instead of `sys.path[:0] = …` to prepend some paths, and it took forever to spot why it was breaking my stdlib…

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and this is what I get with the path:['', '/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']

Comment: if i need to reinstall what is the safest way to delete and reinstall pls?

Comment: @user42967. As a sanity check, please run `python2.7 -c 'import itertools'`. Do you get a traceback?

Comment: no same error unfortunately

Comment: OK, it looks like your path is reasonable, and somehow `itertools` isn't in that path. You could try manually checking each of those zipfiles and directories if you want to be really sure it's not there before giving up and reinstalling, but you'll probably find it isn't there.

Comment: Anyway, I assume this is the Ubuntu default Python 2.7? If so, you should be able to just `apt-get install --reinstall` it, but that's really more of a question for askubuntu than SO.

Comment: I tried apt-get install --reinstall...no success...i will try askubuntu...thanks for the help